# how to use update query in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to update cached_name column of callog.calls table in android,but getting sql lite exception .I have been trying this for long but could not able to come up with anything.I have searched a lot but could not find sufficient information about update statement.kindly help.

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); 

            Cursor cur = cr.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
value.put("CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME","frank");
  cr.update(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,value,CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, null);

Error:

11-25 20:11:17.755: ERROR/Database(106): Error updating CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME=frank using UPDATE calls SET CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME=? WHERE name

11-25 20:11:17.776: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(106): Writing exception to parcel

11-25 20:11:17.776: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(106): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error: , while compiling: UPDATE calls SET CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME=? WHERE name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your call to update is wrong. It needs to look like this:

```
cr.update(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,value,null, null);
```

that will update all the values in the table. To update a specific row do:

```
cr.update(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,value,CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME +" = ?", new String[]{oldName});
```

where oldName is the value to use in your WHERE clause.

Comment: cr.update(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,value,CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME+"=?", new String[]{""});...I used this as name was initially null.but now  getting neither exception nor getting updation in db.any idea.

Comment: that would update any row where the CACHED_NAME column is equal to the empty string '' (not a null string, but a 0 character string). Do you have such a row in your table?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to go through these links, for better understanding all the concepts of using Sqlite in Android.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954